# Scala List[Any] has a element as function. How to get return value?

Tags: scala, list, function

I'm a novice in Scala and this moment I'm learning about it... I'm testing code and I have a list[Any] like this:

```scala
  var list: List[Any] = List(
    "a string",
    732, // an integer
    'c', // a character
    true, // a boolean value
    (x: String) => "String return " + x)
```

I want to get return value of index 4, but I obtain an error. I don't know how to get the return value.. that is my doubt.

```scala
var test = list(4);
test("hello") // Error
```

Comment: What's the error? That's pretty important.

Comment: You may need to cast the function as a function, since as far as the compiler is concerned, `test` is if type `Any`, which it can't guarantee is callable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the function from `Any` to `String => String` before invoking it:

```
var test = list(4)

test.asInstanceOf[String => String]("hello")
// res21: String = String return hello
```

---

Or:

```
val test = list(4).asInstanceOf[String => String]
// test: String => String = <function1>

test("hello")
// res23: String = String return hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like so:

```
scala> val f = (x: String) => "String return " + x
f: String => String = <function1>
scala> val y = f.asInstanceOf[ String => String ].apply("x")
y: String = String return x
scala> val y = f.asInstanceOf[ String => String ]("x")
y: String = String return x
```